# Moving one polygon layers data to another polygon layer based on distance

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, spatial-join

I'm trying to set variable shape polygons to a hexagon grid. I want to do something like a spatial join, but without merging data as in "One_to_one", and only having one polygon fill one hexagon unlike "One_to_many"

Here is a subset:

[image: Variable shape to hexagon]

I was thinking that I can calculate centroid of the polygons and match them to the closest hexagon, but I don't know how to just match one polygon to one hexagon.

In the end it should look something like this:

[image: Hexagons matched to polygons]

Comment: I'm kind of looking for feature mapping with a 1:1 match, but that only works on line features not polygons. http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/editing-toolbox/about-feature-matching-and-the-match-table.htm

Comment: how many polygons are there?

Comment: 1409 polygons and a matching number of hexagons

Comment: I'm still having no luck, converted the polygons to points so I could make a "point distance" table and then export to Access2013 to do a Query for the smallest distances and get a list, but it looks like I will just want to do 100 iterations of "near" and manually remove polygons each round as they match.